# How can I add if active = undefined in handlebar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, handlebars.js

I have give if Active something, else something but my some of my Active features data it fetches are undefined how can I change it with handlebars?

```
{{#if Active}}
<span class="profile__list-key">Active:</span>
<span class="o-labels o-labels--support-maintained">{{Active}}</span>
{{else}}
<span class="profile__list-key">Active:</span>
<span class="o-labels o-labels--support-deprecated">{{Active}}</span>
{{/if}}
</li>
```

At the moment my Active : true, or Active: false
If it could't fetch the data which is undefined my Active : got red box but no true or false

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom helpers like:

```
if_eq: function(a, b, opts) {
        if (a == b) {
            return opts.fn(this);
        } else {
            return opts.inverse(this);
        }
}
```

Refer: https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Comment: Not sure how do I do this.

Comment: if my object fetches Active = undefined how can I not show false in handlebars

Comment: if (a == 'undefined') or even (!a) { return true; } would work. First try using such custom helper then just play around, its plain js.